# Core graphics draw rectangle with border in one line

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

How can I draw a rectangle with a border in one line?

There are separate methods like:

```
CGContextStrokeRect(context, someRectangle);
```

and

```
CGContextFillRect(context, someRectangle);
```

but is there something that does both in one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Although, I can't say it's any less verbose than stroke & fill in separate calls...

Comment: Hmm... very true, I'll just go with separate calls I suppose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you're just looking to save line space, you could define your own method to make two calls and place it in a utility class.

```
void strokeAndFill(CGContextRef c, CGRect rect)
{
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);
    CGContextStrokeRect(c, rect);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CGContextDrawPath does it one go if you set fill and stroke color beforehand.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, a);
CGContextSetFillColor(context, b);
CGContextDrawPath(context, rect)
```

Comment: Hmm...  the signature of `CGContextDrawPath` I see in the header file is: `CGContextDrawPath(CGContextRef c, CGPathDrawingMode mode)`